# Fancy frame on "How to format" not looking good

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm guessing this is a dupe of something that was already corrected for "How to ask" (as I don't see the frame there).

This was on the edit page (as a low-rep editor)

[image]

**Bump** same thing on [elections page(s)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/side-bar-formatting-problem-on-the-elections-page)

Comment: Same problem as [“How to Tag” instructions overflow their box](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/531/how-to-tag-instructions-overflow-their-box) and [Review page instructions overflow their box](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/519/review-page-instructions-overflow-their-box).

Comment: And same as (the more recent than this) [Design bug when editing an old revision](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/668/design-bug-when-editing-an-old-revision)

Comment: I think this needs to be tagged status-completed (otherwise the community user will keep bumping it to the top occasionally).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it in Safari anymore, though I used to. Now, the fancy frame is gone.