# Side bar formatting problem on the elections page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've noticed a side bar formatting problem on [elections page](https://english.stackexchange.com/election).

The fancy border doesn't stretch with the content ...

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: These pesky bards!

Answer (score 3):

A fix has been pushed, yay Jin! (:

Comment: yes. well, it's "partially" fixed. I just realized I i forgot to include the side bar lines in the fix. But i pushed a fix2.0, should be in the next push.