# Fancy frame on election nomination page overflows

Tags: bug, status-completed

This is how the left-side frame on https://english.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination looks like in Safari:

> [image: Screenshot of the issue]

I know it has already been reported [there](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/side-bar-formatting-problem-on-the-elections-page), but the question was marked **status-completed**, which is clearly not the case!

Answer (score 2):

I messed up the 2nd fix again. bad me. a new fix will be in the next deployment.